# How to merge two files line by line backwards

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a code that merges in line by line two text files backwards. I just want to know if I have the right idea of using `while` and `if` statement, and switching `SEEK_SET` to `SEEK_END` with the `0` becoming a  `-1`? Currently the second file is just displaying ÿ's but am working on that, also ignore some of the code as it is counting statistics. I have tried some debugging but I'm not great at it. This would  be `input1.txt` for example:

> There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but
>   the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected
>   humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
>   If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure
>   there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All
>   the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined
>   chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the
>   Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with
>   a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which
>   looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free
>   from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
//setting names of ints and chars.

FILE *file_in, *file_in2, *file_out;
int wordcount, linecount, charcount, i = 100;
char letter, letter2;
char filename1[50];
char filename2[50];
char output [50];

//setting all counts to 0.
wordcount = 0;
linecount = 0;
charcount = 0;


//Gets the user to enter name of file, then puts it in string.
printf("\n Enter first text document\n");
scanf("%s", filename1);
printf("\n Enter Second text document\n");
scanf("%s", filename2);

//opens then reads the first file and checks if the document has opened correctly.
file_in = fopen(filename1, "r");
if (file_in == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "The %s file failed to open!", filename1);
    return 1;
}


// counts the number of words, then lines, then letters in doc 1.
while ((letter = getc(file_in)) != EOF)
{
    if (letter == ' ')
    {
        wordcount++;
    }
    else if (letter == '\n')
    {
        linecount++;
    }
    else
    {
        charcount++;
    }
}


//opens then reads the second file and checks if the document has opened correctly.
file_in2 = fopen(filename2, "r");
if (file_in2 == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "The %s file failed to open!", filename2);
    return 1;
}


// counts the number of words, then lines, then letters in doc 2.
while ((letter2 = getc(file_in2)) != EOF)
{
    if (letter2 == ' ')
    {
        wordcount++;
    }
    else if (letter2 == '\n')
    {
        linecount++;
    }
    else
    {
        charcount++;
    }
}


//displays the total on screen.
printf("words: %d\n", wordcount);
printf("Lines: %d\n", linecount);
printf("Characters: %d\n", charcount);

//asks for output file name
printf("Enter output file: ");
scanf("%s", output);

//opens the output file to write
file_out = fopen (output, "w");
fseek(file_in, 0, SEEK_SET);
fseek(file_in2, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (((letter = getc(file_in)) != EOF) || ((letter2 = getc(file_in2)) != EOF))
{
    fputc(letter, file_out);
    if (letter == '\n')
    {

    }
    fputc(letter2, file_out);
    if (letter2 == '\n')
    {

    }
}



fclose(file_in);
fclose(file_out);
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some example input, and the expected output? Also what is your actual output from the example input? And have you tried some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or even stepped through the code line by line in an actual debugger?

Comment: `letter` and `letter2` should properly be of type `int` which is the type returned by `getchar`, and note too that you are comparing them with `' '` and `'\n'` which are also of type `int`, not `char`. Not so bad with a text file because it is unlikely to contain the `0xFF` which will be confused with `EOF`. Once you work with a binary file, use of the `char` type will not work as expected.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The code that you provide does not do anything like a line-by-line merge. Please provide examples of input and expected output.